# LibGDX - ShaderProgram won't compile

Tags: libgdx, glsl, shader

I'm trying to set the shader of the `SpriteBatch` in LibGDX 1.6.1.
The problem is that the shader does not compile.

Vertex shader:

```
attribute vec3 a_position;

uniform mat4 u_projTrans;

void main() {
   gl_Position = u_projTrans * vec4(a_position, 1.0);
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
uniform sampler2D u_texture;
void main() {
   gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

I think this code is ok, but the log says: "error C1066: invalid type in type constructor" and "error C1035: assignment of incompatible types". And the compilation status is false. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using `1.9.6` and not tested on `1.6.1`

Vertex shader :

```
attribute vec3 a_position;
uniform mat4 u_projTrans;

void main()
{
   gl_Position =  u_projTrans * vec4(a_position,1.0);
}
```

Fragment shader :

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

void main() {

   gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0);
}
```

Then In code :

```
ShaderProgram shaderProgram=new ShaderProgram(Gdx.files.internal("test.vert.glsl"),Gdx.files.internal("test.frag.glsl"));
shaderProgram.pedantic=false;

if(shaderProgram.isCompiled()){
    batch.setShader(shaderProgram);
}else {
    Gdx.app.log("ShaderTest", shaderProgram.getLog());
}
```

Comment: thanks, the `shaderProgram.pedantic = false` worked :)